# Is the heading in this webpage properly aligned?

Tags: website-design, page-layout, critique, alignment, balance

In [this webpage](https://integrable.net/microsoft-flow/merge-pdf) (see first screenshot below) is the page title (Merge PDF) properly aligned/balanced?

I placed it aligned with the logo (Integrable, in the left) and the blue button, but it doesn't look right either (see second screenshot below)

**First screenshot:**

[image]

**Second screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - ***Please*** look through **[tour]** to get a sense of what our community is about; *then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a **good** query here, *and* how best to frame it. We have some specific requirements for critique questions; please read [ask] and edit your question to better fit our guidelines - though honestly you're pretty close now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First screenshot looks better.

Titles need some space around to separate from the rest of the content and interface elements. That title is the main element on the page and should be allowed space to stand out, as a reader's eyes will jump back and forth between ↔ logo ↔ title ↔ button ↔ so you can't stick these too close together.

Don't be afraid of whitespace, think of it as an invisible border between sections. Best trick in the world is to look at apple.com and see how they use whitespace for everything.

Scrap that second option.

Comment: Hi Lucian, this is a very subjective answer. Please [edit] it to include information on _why_ the first option is better (e.g. breathing room, focus, ...)

Comment: Hi. The question is also subjective, but yes i do get the point and made some edits.

Comment: When the question is subjective maybe better VTC instead of answering...

Comment: Many times i actually do, but in this case, even if its technically opinion based, most designers will pretty much say the same thing. The second screen is a non-design, so It made sense to answer this.